# Random values being written in DynamoDB session

Tags: session, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use DynamoDB for storing sessions, 
but everytime I try to write an integer into the session variable,
some other random value is being written.

Reading is happening correctly.
I don't know what the issue is?

has anybody else faced a similar issue??
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with DynamoDB in my case.
Zend Framework was doing funny stuff to my session before writing it to dynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any code you could share? I suspect it is either 1) the datatype or 2) some other part of the code, unrelated to DynamoDB.